# SQL: All records from one table, and all records from another, including null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008.

Hi guys, I have a table called `Language` all I need from this table is `LanguageID` (1-10).
I have another table called `UserQuiz` and I need the `ModuleID` and a `COUNT()` of Passed.
The plan is to show 10 languages with 4 modules with a users passed count.

So it would be 40 records(LanguageIDs * ModuleIDs).
But not all languages have All Modules and thus don't have any records.

I need a query that will just fill in the missing module and put null in the record for usercount.

So far I've tried...

UPDATED:: 29/08/2013 @ 10:35 am (GMT).

```
CREATE TABLE #CrossTable(
LanguageID int,
ModuleID int
)
INSERT INTO #CrossTable
SELECT LanguageID, ModuleID 
FROM 
RoundupAcademy.dbo.Languages
CROSS JOIN
RoundupAcademy.dbo.CurrentModules
/*********************************************************************************/

/** get users via date and quiz **************************************************/
CREATE TABLE #userspassed(
userid int,
passed int,
moduleid int,
languageid int
)
INSERT INTO #userspassed
SELECT userprofile.UserId, passed, userquiz.moduleID, LanguageId
FROM 
UserProfile
LEFT JOIN 
UserQuiz
ON
UserProfile.UserId = UserQuiz.userID
WHERE
((Convert(datetime,LastLogin, 120) >= 
    Convert(datetime,@datefrom, 120) 
AND (Convert(datetime,LastLogin, 120) <= 
        convert(datetime,@datetoo, 120))))
AND
(passed is null or passed = 1)
/*********************************************************************************/

/**Get Modules per language count on users passed ********************************/
SELECT 
#CrossTable.languageID, 
#CrossTable.ModuleID,
coalesce(COUNT(#userspassed.userID),0) as users 
FROM 
#CrossTable
LEFT JOIN
#userspassed
ON 
#CrossTable.ModuleID = #userspassed.moduleID
GROUP BY #CrossTable.LanguageID, #CrossTable.ModuleID

/*********************************************************************************/
```

this does bring back 40 records but module "n" that is repeated 10 times for language also has repeated Users(count).  seems there is only 4 values that is being applied to 10 of the languages for module 1 (value 94) and 10 for module 2 (value 89) and  10 for module 3 (value 104) and 10 for module 4 (value 28).

Each record should be different but it seems its applying the same values to all modules that are the same.

UPDATED:: 29/08/2013 @ 11:05 am (GMT).

I forgot to add

```
AND 
#CrossTable.LanguageID = #userspassed.languageid
```

seems to work now just going to check the values are correct

Comment: If you don't have a definitive list of the modules somewhere, then there's no guarantee that you'll get back 40 records. Maybe no user whatsoever passed that combination.

To check it, take the users out of the equation and write a query that returns the languages and modules. If you get the 40 rows you're looking for, it's not a big jump to add in the users afterwards.

Comment: You need to use a `CROSS JOIN` to get the cartesian product of all languages with all modules. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx for details.

Comment: @StephenO'Flynn Im using my language table as the definitive table, ModuleIDs are stored in there own table, Only problem is its one table with moduleID and name. So how would I use this table to make usre i pull all 40 records?

Comment: @MicSim Ive already had a crack at Cross join, but the results go completely messed up, Could you clarify Where you would use A Cross join in this example to get the desired result?

Comment: @MicSim As far as i understand I would need to Cross join Language and module to get the cartesian product(40 records), then i can left join that to my user count?

Comment: You would have to cross join the exactly 10 LanguageIDs to the exactly 4 ModuleIDs. All other joins can remain the same. I don't know where you store your module data. Possibly you need to extract them with a separate query from another table first.

Comment: as you typed that thats exactly what im trying now, think i understand the concept of cross join, just going to quickly check this and let you know, if it works post it as a answer and ill flag it as correct

Comment: @MicSim ive updated my query and now have 40 results although im getting strange records (basically all records for module 1 are valued at 94...when each one should be diff)

Comment: All records from one table, and all records from another table. UNION ALL?

Comment: @SelectDistinct Sorry i fail to see how a union could be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe link to the language on the JOIN as well. Also you shouldn't need a COALESCE on a COUNT:

```
SELECT 
    #CrossTable.languageID, 
    #CrossTable.ModuleID,
    COUNT(#userspassed.userID) as users 
FROM 
    #CrossTable
LEFT JOIN
    #userspassed ON 
      #CrossTable.LanguageID = #userspassed.languageid
      AND #CrossTable.ModuleeID = #userspassed.moduleid
GROUP BY #CrossTable.LanguageID, #CrossTable.ModuleID
```

Comment: just as you posted i just figured it out haha

Comment: why do i not need a COALESCE?

Comment: Because COUNT should return 0 if there's no records. COALESCE is used when you want to replace a NULL with something known or concrete.

Comment: Meanwhile, if it helped at all, would you mind accepting the answer?